# Software to use Windows based user workstations for backup and storage

Tags: file-management, backup, file-synchronization, cloud-storage

Is there a program that can take advantage of all of the unutilized storage on 500+ Windows workstations spread out across our network?

I was thinking of a server software that would appear as one large drive that pools together the resources from all of the workstations into one file store.  When a file is copied to the server, it is distributed across one or more client workstations across the network.

Of course security might be an issue, but I'm hoping the solution would account for that with some sort of encryption.  Also, I'm hoping the solution would allow for redundancy, copying the file to multiple workstations, so that workstations could drop off or be replaced without impacting the storage.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Sounds like a task for [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/). Not tried it, but your description matches one of its features: per client you can define which parts it should automatically sync completely (i.e. MetaData *and* content); from other parts it only syncs MetaData. so "virtually" everything's available everywhere, every client knows what's available at which peer, and none of them *has to* have everything (but of course can).

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/688079/how-can-i-utilise-unused-space-on-a-large-network-in-a-decentralised-yet-resilie

Comment: That sounds very similar to git-annex indeed (including redundancy) :)

Comment: [Distributed file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems#Distributed_file_systems).